# How can I assert parameter binding will succeed without side effects?

Tags: powershell, dependency-injection, parameters, assert

Suppose I have a function into which a dependency and some parameters are injected like the following:

```
function Invoke-ACommandLaterOn
{
    param
    (
        # ...
        [string]   $CommandName,
        [object]   $PipelineParams,
        [object[]] $PositionalParams,
        [hashtable]$NamedParams
        # ...
    )

    Assert-ParameterBinding @PSBoundParameters
    # ...
    # Some complicated long-running call tree that eventually invokes 
    # something like
    # $PipelineParams | & $CommandName @PositionalParams @NamedParams
    # ...
}
```

I would like to immediately assert that binding of the parameters to `$CommandName` succeeds.  That's what `Assert-ParameterBinding` is meant to do.  I'm not exactly sure how to implement `Assert-ParameterBinding`, however.

Of course I could try to invoke `$CommandName` immediately, but in this case doing so has side-effects that cannot occur until a bunch of other long-running things are completed first.

How can I assert parameter binding to a function will succeed without invoking the function?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Why don't you use `[Parameter()]` validation attributes?

Comment: Is the command behind `$CommandName` always defined by you? Can that target be modified?

Comment: @briantist No.  `$CommandName` could be any command.  In my case it's a mix of common commands like `New-Item` and custom commands.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 This question is about immediate assertion that parameter binding would succeed on a (yet) hypothetical call.  I don't see how using (or not using) `[Parameter()]` has any impact on implementing such an assertion.

Comment: I don't know how you can assert something you don't know until the case comes up.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 All the information is already known: The command name and its arguments is sufficient for PowerShell to perform parameter binding and those are known.  The Pester `Mock` command does a form of this very thing.

Answer (score 1):

What if you did something like this (inside the `Assert-` function):

```
$cmd = Get-Command $CommandName
$meta = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new($cmd)
$proxy = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($meta)

$code = $proxy -ireplace '(?sm)(?:begin|process|end)\s*\{.*','begin{}process{}end{}'

$sb = [scriptblock]::Create($code)

$PipeLineParams | & $sb @PositionalParams @NamedParams
```

I'm actually not sure if it will work with the positional params or with splatting two different sets, off the top of my head (and I didn't do much testing).

## Explanation

I had a few thoughts. For one, parameter binding can be very complex. And in the case of a pipeline call, binding happens differently as different blocks are hit.

So it's probably a good idea to let PowerShell handle this, by essentially recreating the same function but with a body that does nothing.

So I went with the built in way to generate a proxy function since it takes care of all that messy work, then brutally replaced the body so that it doesn't actually call the original.

Ideally then, you'll be making a call that follows all the regular parameter binding process but in the end accomplishes nothing.

Wrapping that in a `try`/`catch` or otherwise testing for errors should be a pretty good test of whether this was a successful call or not.

This even handles dynamic parameters.

There are probably edge cases where this won't quite work, but I think they will be rare.

Additionally, `ValidateScript` attributes and dynamic parameters could conceivably create side effects.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll tinker with this concept.  I agree that it would be best to have PowerShell attempt to do the binding.

Comment: @alx9r the code I posted definitely needs work, but I think the concept is sound. Curious what you'll end up with either way!

Comment: You might be interested in [this experiment](https://github.com/nohwnd/Mock) that @nohwnd and I have been working on.

Comment: @alx9r definitely! Following that project now